# Сравнение указателей на строковые литералы

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, строковый-литерал

```
const char* p = "Heraclitus" 
const char* q = "Heraclitus" 
void g ()
{
    if(p==q) cout<<"one! \n"; //результат зависит от конкретной реализации
}
```

Б. Страуструп

Суть в том что адреса разные, а пишут вот что:

> Обратите внимание на то, что для указателей операция `==` сравнивает
>   адреса (значения указателей), а не адресуемые ими величины.

Если сравниваются адреса, то как может быть `true`, если при компиляции явно разные адреса?

Comment: А вы [уверены](https://ideone.com/f4s7hx)?

Comment: Не ясно, о чем вопрос? Ясно же написано: результат зависит от реализации. И это так. Может быть `true`, а может быть `false`. Что вы имеете в виду под "при компиляции явно разные адреса"? С чего это вдруг "явно"?

Comment: @AnT После этого я добавил код:if (p==b) cout << "true" << &p << " " << &b;

Comment: @AnT Адреса, полученные моим путем .оказались разными, вот вопрос и возник. Сам себя запутал этим действием. При условии &p==&b все встало на свои места=) оно не может быть true =)

Comment: Не может быть 2 объявленных переменных занимающих один и тот-же  адрес. Вот что я хотел понять. =)

Comment: Увас переменные, это указатели. Их адреса конечно разные, но они могут хранить адрес начала одного и того же обьекта.   p == q   сравнивает не адреса указателей, а их содержание, а именно адреса обьектов, хранящихся в этих указателей

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Компилятору разрешается (но не требуется) в качестве оптимизации хранить одинаковые строковые литералы* в одном и том же месте. Если компилятор это делает, то адреса будут одинаковые. Если не делает - разные.

---

<sub>*Литерал - безымянная константа в исходном коде. `x`, `'y'`, `123`, `"hello"` - все это литералы. `"hello"` - строковый литерал.</sub>

Comment: скорее просто не создается вторая область памяти, для хранения идентичных обьектов